# How to find the "effective" end of a Range?

Tags: ruby, range

The `.end` of a Ruby range is the number used to specify the end of the range, whether or not the range is "exclusive of" the end. I don't understand the rationale for this design decision, but never the less, I was wondering what the most idiomatic mechanism is for determining the "effective end" of the range (i.e. greatest integer `n` such that `range.include?(n)` is `true`. The only mechanism I know of is `last(1)[0]`, which seems pretty klunky.

Comment: Does `max` give the required output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`Range#max`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Range.html#method-i-max) method:

```
r = 1...10
r.end
# => 10
r.max
# => 9
```

`max` won't work for exclusive ranges if any of the endpoints is `Float` (see `range_max` in [`range.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_353/range.c#L930-L960) for details):

```
(1.0...10.0).max
# TypeError: cannot exclude non Integer end value

(1.0..10.0).max
# => 10.0
```

As an exception, if `begin > end`, no error is raised and `nil` is returned:

```
(2.0...1.0).max
# => nil
```

**Update**: `max` works in costant time for any inclusive range and exclusive ranges of integers, it returns the same value as `end` and `end-1`, respectively. It is also *O(1)* if for the range holds that `begin > end`, in this case `nil` is returned. **For exlusive ranges of non integer objects (`String`, `Date`, ...) or when a block is passed, it calls `Enumerable#max` so it have to travel all the elements in the range!**

Comment: As OP asking for *integer* we can convert `(1.0...10.0)` to **integer** version: `r = 1.0...10.0; r2 = Range.new r.begin.to_i, r.end.to_i, r.exclude_end?;`. On other hand, if we define `pred` and `succ` in `Float` we can `iterate` over it(for example: `to_a`) so we can use `minmax`, get second value, and convert it to integer. So.. yeah, first method is easier and is more precise. ps. we cannot use `max` because it checks if *elements of range* are integers, and works with integers only.

Comment: Does `.max` travel the all elements of the Range?

Comment: @steenslag This is quite a question by itself! :-)